# How do I convert a calendar week into a date in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a week number and a year, and would like to calculate the date of the Monday for that specific week in Microsoft Excel.

```
Year   Week   Date (Monday)
2012   1      January 2, 2012
2013   16     April 15, 2013
2014   42     October 13, 2014
```

What formula can I use to convert a calendar week to a specific date?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For ISO week numbers you can use this formula to get the Monday

`=DATE(A2,1,-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,1,3))+B2*7`

assuming year in A2 and week number in B2

it's the same as my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855872/1124287

Comment: This works ok but you have to use semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: Whether you use commas or semi-colons as "argument separators" is dependant on your regional settings - for me it works with commas. In regions where a comma is usually used as the decimal separator then usually semi-colons will be required

Answer (score 2):

The following formula is suitable for every year. You don't need to adjust it anymore.
The precondition is that Monday is your first day of the week.

```
If A2 = Year and Week = B2
=IF(ISOWEEKNUM(DATE($A$2;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A$2;1;1);2)+1)>1;DATE($A$2;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A$2;1;1);2)+1+B2*7;DATE($A$2;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($A$2;1;1);2)-6+B2*7)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your week number is in A1 and the year is in A2, following snippet could give you dates of full week

```
=$A$1*7+DATE($B$1,1,-4) through =$A$1*7+DATE($B$1,1,2)
```

Of course complete the series from -4 to 2 and you'll have dates starting Sunday through Saturday.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the week number is in `A1` and the year in `A2`, you can try:

```
A1*7+DATE(A2,1,1)
```

Comment: that won't necessarily give you a Monday date though?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to do this formula:

```
A1*7+DATE(A2,1,1)
```

If it returns a Wednesday, simply change the formula to:

```
(A1*7+DATE(A2,1,1))-2
```

This will only work for dates within one calendar year.

Answer (score 0):

If A1 has the week number and year as a 3 or 4 digit integer in the format wwYY then the formula would be:

```
=INT(A1/100)*7+DATE(MOD([A1,100),1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(MOD(A1,100),1,1))-5
```

the subtraction of the weekday ensures you return a consistent start day of the week. Use the final subtraction to adjust the start day.

Answer (score 0):

=(MOD(R[-1]C-1,100)*7+DATE(INT(R[-1]C/100+2000),1,1)-2)

yyww as the given week exp:week 51 year 2014 will be 1451

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the opposite to get a date from a weeknumber i found a solution online and changed it slightly:

```
Function fnDateFromWeek(iYear As Integer, iWeek As Integer, iWeekDday As Integer)
  ' get the date from a certain day in a certain week in a certain year
  fnDateFromWeek = DateSerial(iYear, 1, (iWeek * 7) _
          + iWeekDday - Weekday(DateSerial(iYear, 1, 1)) + 1)
End Function
```

I took the [formular from asap-utilities.com/](http://www.asap-utilities.com/excel-tips-detail.php?categorie=9&m=75) and changed

```
DateSerial(iYear, 1, ((iWeek - 1) * 7)
```

to

```
DateSerial(iYear, 1, (iWeek * 7)
```

### Update

It seems that at least for germany the formular works not as expected for the **leap year 2016** so i changed it to this

```
Function fnDateFromWeek(iYear As Integer, iWeek As Integer, iWeekDday As Integer)
' get the date from a certain day in a certain week in a certain year
  
    If isLeapYear(iYear) Then
        curDate = DateSerial(iYear, 1, ((iWeek) * 7) _
          + iWeekDday - Weekday(DateSerial(iYear, 1, 1)) + 1)
    Else
        curDate = DateSerial(iYear, 1, ((iWeek - 1) * 7) _
          + iWeekDday - Weekday(DateSerial(iYear, 1, 1)) + 1)
    End If
    fnDateFromWeek = curDate
End Function
```

Since 2016 hardcoded is not ideal you could [check if a year is a leap year](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-date-function) with this function

```
Function isLeapYear(iYear As Integer) As Boolean

    If (Month(DateSerial(iYear, 2, 29)) = 2) Then
        isLeapYear = True
    Else
        isLeapYear = False
    End If
    
End Function
```

For a non-leap-year `DateSerial(iYear,2 ,29)` returns 1st of march

This may still be wrong but my limited test gave the expected results:

```
Sub TestExample()
   Debug.Print Format(fnDateFromWeek(2014, 48, 2), "ddd dd mmm yyyy") ' mo 24 Nov 2014
   Debug.Print Format(fnDateFromWeek(2015, 11, 6), "ddd dd-mmm-yyyy") ' fr 13 Mar 2015
   Debug.Print Format(fnDateFromWeek(2016, 36, 2), "ddd dd-mmm-yyyy") ' Mo 05 Sep 2015
End Sub
```