# Convert year and ISO-week to date in Excel?

Tags: excel

The year is A1=2012
The ISO-week is A2=1

As I understand it the standard way to decide to which month a week belongs is to look at in which month the Thursday occurs.

Thus, I would like to find the date of the Thursday with year A1 and ISO week A2. How can I find the date of the Thursday?

I know that this thread is related, but I can't figure this out: [calculate the month from the year and week number in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847678/calculate-the-month-from-the-year-and-week-number-in-excel/10855872#10855872)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Thursday of week 1 will always be the first Thursday of the year, then you obviously add 7 for each week after that, so you can get the Thursday date with this formula

`=DATE(A1,1,1+A2*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,1,3))`

with Year in A1 and ISO week number in A2

Comment: This formula does exactly what it is described to do: calculate the Thursday of the week, and that is the correct answer to the question that was asked. If you want to find the Monday of that week, you have to subtract 3: `=DATE(A1,1,1+A2*7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,1,3))-3`. Also notice that `WEEKDAY` returns 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To find the date defined by (A1,B1,C1) where A1 = ISO Year, B1 = ISO Week, and C1 = the day of the week, assuming week starts with Monday, day 1, use the following:

In VBA:

```
    S = DateSerial(A1, 1, 3)
    W = Weekday(S)
    D = S - W + 7 * B1 + C1 - 6
```

Or in one formula in Excel:

```
=DATE(A1,1,3) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,1,3)) + 7 * B1 + C1 - 6
```