# Week number based on Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make week number based on given date.

Today   28-08-18
Week     .....

```
        30-07-18    1
        06-08-18    2
        13-08-18    3
        20-08-18    4
        27-08-18    5
        03-09-18    6
        10-09-18    7
        17-09-18    8
        24-09-18    9
        01-10-18    10
        08-10-18    11
        15-10-18    12
        22-10-18    13
        29-10-18    14
```

I want the cell next to "week" to be based on today's date.

Comment: Try to play with `weeknum()` function.. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ That start's counting from the first week of the year and resets with the coming of the new year.

Comment: Are these dates entered as text ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate the month from the year and week number in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847678/calculate-the-month-from-the-year-and-week-number-in-excel)

Comment: just offset the values to match your start week.. eg. `=x-weeknum(<dateData>)` change the x to match your first week. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 30-07-18 is located @ A1. in B1, type in :

```
=WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM($A$1,2)+1
```

and drag it down. Glad that you'd tried. ( :

All the best.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for the simple and clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Start by inserting a date in any cell, that will be the first week.
- Create a function that calculates the difference between its adjacent
  cell and the first and divides it by 7. Voilà you've got the week number. You can round it if you want.

The formula is as follows: Floor((First date - Current date)/7).

Useful link for subtraction: http://www.theexceladdict.com/_t/t040303.htm.

Good luck,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Your base date (BD) may not be the start of the week (SOW), so the general solution could be

1. calculate the `SOW` from your base date: `SOW = BD - WEEKDAY(BD)+2`
2. calculate the distance `DI` from given date (GD) to `SOW`: `DI = GD - SOW`
3. convert distance into weeknumber W = INT(DI/7)

[image]

EDIT:

```
SOW = IF(WEEKDAY(BD)=1;BD-6;BD-WEEKDAY(BD)+2)
```

this is to cover cases where BD is a Sunday and SOW should be the Monday before (not after)

Comment: After reading again, this one actually worked as well. Thanks for the help @MikeD